# Alternate of Sub String on a large size table

Tags: mysql

I have a field named dev_resolution in my table and the table is of around 5 GB. I need to separate the resolution and check if any of the values is greater than 1000.

Example:

```
**Dev_Resolution**
455x500
1024x200
1080x450
```

So, I need to separate: 455 and 500 and then further check if any of the value is greater than 1000 or not.

I have written the following query to separate the values:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(resolution,'x',1) AS first_resolution, SUBSTRING_INDEX(resolution,'x',-1) AS second_resolution, resolution 
FROM table
```

But it takes too long to execute. What could be the alternate of using Substring_index?

Comment: Split it into two columns?

Comment: How long would you expect such an operation to take, on a 5 gigabyte table? To you 3 seconds might be unreasonable, whereas I'd be happy to let that query run for 5 minutes while I make a coffee

Comment: Apparently the resolution column does not hold one piece of data for you, but two. Run a query to split it into two columns and it'll be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an index on the `resolution` column? Because there is no where condition in your query it has to read the whole table. So it depends how big is your table, but an index can still help a lot:

Test table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `resolution` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_resolution` (`resolution`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Test data:

```
select * from t1 order by id;
+----+------------+
| id | resolution |
+----+------------+
|  6 | 455x500    |
|  7 | 1000x500   |
|  8 | 200x600    |
|  9 | 2000x800   |
| 10 | 1400x800   |
| 11 | 600x600    |
+----+------------+
```

If you check the execution plan of your query:

```
explain SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(resolution,'x',1) AS first_resolution, SUBSTRING_INDEX(resolution,'x',-1) AS second_resolution, resolution  FROM t1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: idx_resolution
      key_len: 23
          ref: NULL
         rows: 6
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I have an index on `resolution` and in the `Extra` you can see `Using Index`, that means InnoDB can use the index to give back the result it does not have to read the disk at all (If you have enough memory to hold the index).

Filtering the values is greater than 1000:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(resolution,'x',1) AS first_resolution, SUBSTRING_INDEX(resolution,'x',-1) AS second_resolution, resolution  FROM t1 having first_resolution > 1000 or second_resolution > 1000;
+------------------+-------------------+------------+
| first_resolution | second_resolution | resolution |
+------------------+-------------------+------------+
| 1400             | 800               | 1400x800   |
| 2000             | 800               | 2000x800   |
+------------------+-------------------+------------+
```

As you can see I am using [having](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) to filter the resolutions where it is greater than 1000.

Conclusion:

If there is no index on that `resolution` InnoDB has to scan the whole table which may requires disk reads as well. If there is an index InnoDB could use indexes and give back the results from memory.

The speed depends on how big is the table because no extra filtering.

What could be a better solution?

If you are planning to run this query regularly I would recommend to consider to split this column into two columns: `width` and `height`
If you have index on both you can easily filter on that in the where condition.

Another good solution is to use [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).

New Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `resolution` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `width` smallint(4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(resolution,'x',1)),
  `height` smallint(4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(resolution,'x',-1)),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_resolution` (`resolution`),
  KEY `idx_w` (width),
  KEY `idx_h` (height)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see I generate the `width` and `height` columns from the original `resolution` column. This does not require application changes just an alter table. I also added indexes on these columns.

```
explain select resolution from t2 where width > 1000 or height > 1000\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t2
   partitions: NULL
         type: index_merge
possible_keys: idx_w,idx_h
          key: idx_w,idx_h
      key_len: 3,3
          ref: NULL
         rows: 3
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using sort_union(idx_w,idx_h); Using where
```

As you can see it uses indexes but also do an index merge. If you are alway filtering on both condition you can add a composite index on (width,height) so you can avoid index merge as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need to cut the string up in the where? I think you can do it with math alone

```
SELECT * FROM
  table 
WHERE 
  CHAR_LENGTH(res) >= 8 OR   
  (
    CHAR_LENGTH(res) >= 6 AND 
    LOCATE('x', resolution, 2) - CHAR_LENGTH(res)/2) NOT BETWEEN 0 and 1
  )
```

Any string 8 or longer of the pattern AxB must have at least A or B be 4 or more digits

Any string below 6 long cannot match

Any string 6 or 7 long only matches if the locate-len/2 is outside the range 0-1

```
1x10000, length 7, locate 2, calc -1.5 KEEP
10x1000, length 7, locate 3, calc -0.5 KEEP
100x100, length 7, locate 4, calc 0.5 THROW
1000x10, length 7, locate 5, calc 1.5 KEEP
10000x1, length 7, locate 6, calc 2.5 KEEP
1000x1, length 6, locate 5, calc 2 KEEP
100x10, length 6, locate 4, calc 1 THROW
10x100, length 6, locate 3, calc 0 THROW
1x1000, length 6, locate 2, calc -1 KEEP
```